# Do I neet GDT to build an IDT?

Tags: assembly, x86, osdev

I am working on Atom-32bit board (AT&T assembly), there is no software on this board yet.

Do I need to build GDT to build/use an IDT ?

The idea is just to use an ISR with APIC timer.

```
/*Change the address of idt_entries table */
fill_interrupt(ISR_Nbr,(unsigned int) isr33, 0x08, 0x8E);


static void fill_interrupt(unsigned char num, unsigned int base, unsigned short sel, unsigned char flags)
{
    unsigned short *Interrupt_Address;

    /*address = idt_ptr.base + num * 8 byte*/
    Interrupt_Address = (unsigned short *)(idt_ptr.base + num*8);

    *(Interrupt_Address) = base&0xFFFF;
    *(Interrupt_Address+1) = sel;
    *(Interrupt_Address+1) = (flags>>8)&0xFF00;
    *(Interrupt_Address+1) = (base>>16)&0xFFFF;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved :), as there is a BIOS, it already built the GDT/IDT, so I found there address using sidt and sgdt instructions, and i added my ISR to sidt

Answer (score 2):

Basically, yes. You must have a GDT so that you can have a segment to "point" an IDT interrupt vector at. Note, (as far as I know) you can load both the IDT and GDT at the same time, but you can't make use of the IDT until you have a GDT loaded. If you attempt to you'll, at best, get a triple fault.

Comment: @Alex : some update: I found out that there is a BIOS on the Atom board, so I checked for the IDT and GDT "/*Read the IDTR*/sidt (idt_ptr) /*Read the GDTR*/sgdt (gdt_ptr)" and they existe, it seems like the BIOS made them. I tried to use them (see above the function fill_interrupt), after that i used "int $0x20", PFFFF the code crashed again..... :-(....any clue or remark or question ???

Comment: @must what? Yes, the BIOS probably does load a GDT and IDT but by the de-facto IBM PC standard, you're dropped back into real mode(without GDT or IDT) before it hits your boot loader. Is this "Atom 32bit" board anything special? Is it a typical Intel Atom motherboard used in PCs?

Comment: The board i use is "Intel® Embedded Development Board 1-N450",

Comment: how do i check if an ISR/interrupt is well set in IDT ? is there any registers to look or a test ?, I don't see where is the problem !!!

Comment: Get a GDT loaded first before worrying about the IDT. And there isn't really a better way to test the IDT than to try an `int 50` or whatever. And that board is *basically* (from the OS Dev standpoint) the same as standard IBM PC motherboards. You may want to look at http://osdev.org . They have a very good wiki and a semi-active forum

Comment: :10x, after some investigation i found that the BIOS managed to build IDT/GDT, so right now i try to link "int" to my "ISR"....